# "available" in a vending machine context

Tags: word-usage

There's a vending machine that sells three kinds of canned juices, of which each costs 10, 30, 50 cents, and currently aren't sold out. Now, if I put one quarter(25 cents) into the machine, is the 30-cent juice *available*, because it isn't sold out & I have more money; or is it *unavailable*, because a can of 30-cent juice is not buyable with a quarter, which is all I put in right now?

P.S. I currently have homework that tells me to implement the machine, and the directions: *When a user inserts a coin, vending machine shows all types of available items (Assume that each
item is never out of stock)*. I am perplexed.

Comment: 'Available items' has a stipulative definition meaning either 'generally on sale in these machines' or (as here) 'on sale in this machine at this time, provided (1) you insert money considered appropriate by the mechanism, (2) the machine isn't malfunctioning', (3) someone doesn't switch off the electricity a millisecond after you've inserted your coins ...'. There has to be a pragmatic, sensible interpretation over factors taken into account when using the term 'available'. Here, it's not talking about 'accessible if you add another 5c' but 'available to buy'.

Comment: I think the question is appropriate for ELU. The meaning and implications of *available* has to be deduced from context, everyday English usage, and logic. It's not a programming or engineering question per se.

Comment: Are you asking about the meaning of "available" or do you want to describe whether you can buy juice from a vending machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, availability has nothing to do with whether a customer can afford it. If a mansion is *available* for a million dollars, it doesn’t matter that a prospective buyer only has a hundred thousand dollars. It is still available.

In the context of instructions telling you to display available stock upon the insertion of a coin, you will need to clarify the intent of the assignment. Availability still retains the above sense, and it may be that the intention is simply to be eco-friendly by keeping the display off when no one is looking at it.

This doesn’t change just because every item has unlimited stock. However, that element of context is another prompt for you to clarify the author’s intent.

Answer (score 3):

The instruction would be clearer if worded:

> **After the user inserts each coin, the display updates to show all
> items that can be purchased with the total amount inserted.**

So when the user has inserted a coin that brings the *total* amount inserted from under 10 cents to 10 cent or higher, all 10-cent items should display as "available."  The same holds for reaching (at least) 30 cents and, finally, 50 cents, when all items should display as available.  **If you deposit a quarter as your first coin, only the 10-cent items should display as available**.

I think it's safe to assume that the machine doesn't know (1) how much money you have in your pocket or (2) how much you want to spend. Since it's stipulated that nothing is ever out-of-stock, *available* in this problem can only mean *available for purchase with the amount of money inserted*.  **If nothing is ever out-of-stock and *available* meant simply *for sale*, all items would always be displayed as *available* and you wouldn't have to program anything.**

Don't forget to (1) give (show) any change due after a purchase; (2) reset the total inserted to zero after a purchase and display no items as available; and (3) implement a *Cancel* button that returns all coins the customer has inserted.